# Qt Cryptographic Hashing

Tags: qt

I been trying to use the Qt Encryption libraries and have been having trouble.
The ones that ship with Qt (QCryptographicHash) work well but only support
hash schemes that are insecure like md5 and SHA1, there is no SHA256 for example.

I found the Qt Cryptographic Architecture (QCA) which has much more features.
I got the libraries from the Delta XMPP Project site. http://delta.affinix.com/qca/

The link to the QCA library is http://delta.affinix.com/download/qca/2.0/qca-2.0.3.tar.bz2

It is the newest version of the QCA Libary.

The instruction are as follows.

> ### Installing QCA
>
> QCA requires Qt 4.2 or greater.
>
> ### For Windows:
>
> configure
>   nmake (or make)
>   installwin

Using newest Qt everything. Everything works great in Qt except this library.
I use Windows XP.
I followed the installation instructions and got no errors.

The problem is that I get errors when I try to use any code that has anything to do with the QCA library.  I would really appreciate any help getting this lib to work.

**Here is my code.**

The project file.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2011-11-14T14:23:21
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = kde_crypto2
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
CONFIG   += crypto

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

The source file.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QString>
#include <QtCrypto/QtCrypto>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTextStream t(stdout);

    if(!QCA::isSupported("sha1"))
        t << "SHA1 not supported!\n";
    else
    {
        QByteArray fillerString;
        fillerString.fill('a', 1000);

        QCA::Hash shaHash("sha1");
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
            shaHash.update(fillerString);
        QByteArray hashResult = shaHash.final();
        if ( "34aa973cd4c4daa4f61eeb2bdbad27316534016f" == QCA::arrayToHex(hashResult) )
        {
            t << "big SHA1 is OK\n";
        }
        else
        {
            t << "big SHA1 failed\n";
        }
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Error code is

```
error: conversion from 'QCA::MemoryRegion' to non-scalar type 'QByteArray' requested
```

**EDIT (UPDATE)**
I did not include the --debug-and-release flag when compiling the library.  After re-compiling thelibrary with this flag I no longer get errors while compiling my code. However, when I run my code the application crashes when ever any line is reached that uses the QCA library.  Therefore I believe there is either something wrong with the library or the way it is installed.

The error code when running is:

```
ASSERT: "global" in file qca_core.cpp, line 260
```

Comment: I also had problems with QCA, and it seems like an unmaintained project. I suggest Botan instead. If you make an "amalgamation build" with it (read the docs) it will produce a header and a source file that contains the entire library.
If you want useful answers to your question, you might want to specify your exact errors though, because nobody can guess it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the cause of the error is that you get a `MemoryRegion` with `shaHash.final()` and you try to stuff it into a `QByteArray`. Try adding a `.toByteArray()` after the `final()` call. See http://delta.affinix.com/docs/qca/classQCA_1_1MemoryRegion.html

Whether it makes sense to use QCA (and its maintenance state) I don't know though.

Comment: I made the change you suggested. This is my new build output.
`error: cannot find -lqcad
error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: After re-compiling the QCA library with the --debug-and-release flag and adding your suggestion, the error is as in top post.

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation (http://delta.affinix.com/docs/qca/index.html, "Using QCA")? The library has to be initialized to be used and you can use the QCA::Initializer object for this. Also check the examples, e.g. http://delta.affinix.com/docs/qca/base64test_8cpp-example.html

Comment: Your suggesting about initialization was the key!

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling `Qt` from source you could try this [merge request](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/merge_requests/2475)

> integrated Aaron Gifford BSD licensed SHA-256, SHA-384 and SHA-512
>   functions similar way than original SHA-1 and MD-5 has been done.

I have not tried it myself but the code seems ok and it from the comments I can tell that it will be included in a later release.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not compiling Qt from source, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove the error.

```
QByteArray hashResult = hash.final().toByteArray();
```